# Converting km to miles, feet, yards and inches (More detailed question below)

Tags: c

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    double km, miles, yards, feet, inches;
    scanf("%lf", &km);
    miles = km/1.609;
    printf("%d\n", (int)miles);
    yards = ((km*1093.61) - ((int)miles*1760));
    printf("%d\n", (int)yards);
    feet = (km*3281.4) - ((int)miles*5280 + yards*3);
    printf("%d\n", (int)feet);
    inches = km*39378.498 - ((int)miles*63360 + (int)yards*36 + (int)feet*12);
    printf("%.2lf", inches);
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I managed to write, however it still doesn't pass all tests and isn't 100% accurate as seen in the image below
[image]

Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I "see" a missing cast? `feet = (km*3281.4) - ((int)miles*5280 + /**/(int)/**/yards*3);`

Comment: What is the range of input? won't `(int)miles*63360` overflow?

Comment: Inches is specified to be rounded, but how to convert the first three to integers don't look specified. This problem looks unkind.

Comment: Can you give us an input value for which your code fails the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing code to do conversions such as in your task, it is better to do all (internal) calculations in `double` precision and convert each component part of the result (to `int`) 'on the fly', then subtract each of those converted values as they are determined.

So, first get the conversion into miles as a `double` value, then subtract each integral part and multiply the remainder by the factor required to get the next sub-unit. Using this approach, you are far less likely to encounter problems due to integer overflow and rounding errors.

The following is a potential solution. (Note that it is far better to write *clear* code than attempt to 'compress' many operations into single-line code; the latter is a common cause for bugs creeping into your code and also makes it more difficult for future developers of your code to understand and/or modify it.)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double km = -1.0, total, inches;
    int miles, yards, feet;
    do {
        printf("Enter value in Km: ");
        if (scanf("%lf", &km) != 1) { // Error input: clear buffer
            int c;
            while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
                ;
            if (c == EOF) return 1; // Can't do much after an EOF!
        }
    } while (km < 0.0);

    // First, do the conversion to double "total" ...
    total = km / 1.609;
    // Now, get the integer "miles" value and subtract that from the total ...
    miles = (int)total;
    total -= (double)miles;
    // Next, multiply remainder by 1760 to get the number of yards ...
    total *= 1760.0;
    // Now, get the integer value and subtract that from total ...
    yards = (int)total;
    total -= (double)yards;
    // Multiply remainder by 3 to get feet ...
    total *= 3.0;
    feet = (int)total;
    total -= (double)feet;
    // Finally, multiply remainder by 12 to get inches ...
    inches = total * 12.0;
    // Display result:
    printf("%d %d %d %.2lf\n", miles, yards, feet, inches);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I have also added some code to check that the input value is 'acceptable' (I have chosen to reject negative values, but you can easily change that condition); more importantly, the code will also be able to deal with situations where the user enters a value that cannot be interpreted as a floating-point input (like "Fred"). When using `scanf` for user input, it is always a good idea to check for valid input and handle possible error conditions.

Comment: Note; If you think that the test *must include* the use of negative input values, then let me know. This will require some subtle modifications to the code, which I can easily add as a footnote.